# Adding uncore package to a Chisel project

Tags: scala, riscv, chisel, rocket

There is a file `rocc.scala` in rocket repo which describes `rocc` interface, I want to build its verilog code and see the code. My problem is that I don't know how I can import other packages to my project such as "uncore.*" or "Util.*" and run `SBT`.

Right now for building a new project I just use `build.sbt` and `chisel-dependent.sbt` files located in chisel-tutorial/problems folder

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although chisel may be unfamiliar, it will probably be much more readable than the verilog generated by it. If you are curious about the RoCC interface, I recommend checking out the [slides](http://riscv.org/workshop-jan2015/riscv-rocket-chip-tutorial-bootcamp-jan2015.pdf) from the last RISC-V workshop.

If you really want to look at the generated verilog for these components, I would actually recommend starting with the Rocket-Chip repo. From within that repo, clone the [rocc-template](https://github.com/ucb-bar/rocc-template) and change to the [sha3 branch](https://github.com/ucb-bar/rocc-template/tree/sha3). The Rocket-Chip repo will automatically detect the submodule, and attach it to the RoCC interface. You can also look at the template repo for an example of how to instantiate a project to be incorporated into Rocket-Chip.

Comment: Thanks, I've seen those slides but I need more information about cacheIO part. Right now I'm reading their `rocc-template` repo especially `ctrl` module. But my problem is that there are some parts of the code that I can't understand what is happening even though I've read their tutorial completely. I have a good experience in Verilog, however, that's why I decided to generate .v file and then what is happening in the code

Comment: For example in some part of the code they are using `fire()` function or `busy()` or `debug()` which I don't know what they mean

Comment: fire, busy, and debug are actions done from by Chisel. The Queue is a decoupled interface using ready/valid signaling, and fire indicates an item was transferred (ready & valid). Busy is defined within rocc.scala. In general, I really do recommend reading the Chisel code over reading the verilog output (to understand what it is trying to do).

Comment: Thanks, I see what you are saying.
About debug() do you know what it's doing exactly? I find out about others but debug?

Comment: What are you referring to? Where are you seeing `debug`?